# Model Rule Pattern

Tags: php, yii

I want my pattern allow: a-z (can have accents), A-Z (can have accents), dash, space and dot.
Which way this pattern should be written?

Actual Pattern:

```
array('name','match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => '/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex, i think this is what you're looking for:

```
$str = 'hjkáÁdfgçÇhj.-hj'; // Matches your criteria
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZÁ-ý\-\. ]+$/', $str))
    echo 'match';
else
    echo 'no match';
```

Comment: Not working `array('name','match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-ZÁ-ý\-\. ]+$/'),`

Comment: Could you maybe show more code. For example, how you actually match your results? Because the code i provided works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2Fr3G7

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `^` inside `[]` is ***not*** so what you need is almost the same :-)

`/[a-zA-ZÁ-ý0-9-\s]/u`

to further elaborate what you might need is `/^[a-zA-ZÁ-ý0-9-\s]+$/` which allows the whole string to be only of what's inside the `[]` and as many as you want (the `+` is for as many characters as there are)

Comment: This doesn't match for characters with an accent

Comment: @w00, you are correct! I added the `/u` modifier for unicode.

Comment: Have to point out though that this also accepts chinese, korean, greek (etc.) letters. It also accepts characters like `<>()*&^...etc`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
array('name','match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => ''^([a-zA-ZÁ-ý\-\. ]+)^'')
```